# CF robust debugging not displaying in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have Robust Exception Information enabled in CF administrator (CF10 developer). I recently started using Chrome (51.0.2704.103) and the debugging output isn't displaying. I see the output in Firefox and IE but not in Chrome. I have tried classic and dockable. I think this is a Chrome issue and will report it to Google, I just wanted to see whether any cf devs have encountered this problem and have a solution.

[Windows 7 enterprise, CF10 developer on Apache]

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is picky about the Selected IP Addresses for Debug Output. I had "127.0.0.1". It wanted "::1"